# Yii2 migration on ms sql server returns error: could not find driver

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2, database-migration

I have yii2 project and connected to ms sql server. I have added dll files necessary for connection to ms sql server and put them in xampp/php/ext and put them in php.ini. I'm using PHP 7.2

This is the dll files that I installed and set in my php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x86
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64
extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x86
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64
extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86
```

After that I install odbc driver 11. I open yii2's default login page and input random username and password, then I got this error:

> The table does not exist: {{%user}}

It's because I haven't executed the first migration yet, so user table has not been created yet. This means yii2 has successfully connected to ms sql server, right?

The problem is, when I tried the migration, I got this error:

> Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'could not find driver'

What could be the problem? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: please install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 and restart Apache server

Comment: That's for PHP 5.4, 5.5 and 5.6 while I'm using PHP 7